# Open all xml files in a folder and save only few information

Tags: r, regex, xml

I have no idea how xml works and this is why I ask here.

I am trying to open all the XML files in a folder with this code:

```
library(xml2)
filenames <- list.files("PATH/", pattern="*.xml", full.names=TRUE)
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read_xml)
res <- lapply(ldf, summary)
names(res) <- substr(filenames, 6, 30)
```

After that I have this:
[image]

It is possible create a single file for each ldf ? One ldf is one XML

Comment: You have a typo: change `pattern="*.xlm"` to `pattern="*.xml"`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know I can I change the code below and see the XML like a unique file? I mean not different list for each xml

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. Do you have multiple XML files? What do you mean by unique?

Comment: Is the second part.. All XML is like the first image (different list). How can read the XML like single file? First XML, single list - second XML, single list ecc..

Comment: You cannot. They are different files. You need to read them in, use `regex` to extract what you need from each, and assign them to variables/dataframe. Then you can combine the result to a single dataframe or a vector, etc.

Comment: They are different file also if the XML is the same?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your comment, Maybe because it's too late for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would like to combine it into a single file, but to do so you have to make a new xml document and add each separate file in turn. For instance:

```
library(xml2)

filenames <- list.files("PATH/", pattern = ".*\\.xml$", full.names = TRUE)

ldf <- lapply(filenames, read_xml)

doc <- xml_new_root("doc")

for (i in seq_along(ldf)) {
  xml_add_child(doc, ldf[[i]])
}
```

Now `doc` is an xml_document object containing all "ldfs". You can save the document as an xml file using `write_xml(doc, "all_ldfs.xml")`.

(My suspicion is that what you really want is to extract information from each file and combine that into a single data set? Then please write a new question where you provide example xml files and an explanation of what information you want to extract.)

Comment: Congratulations on understanding the question!